# Vector subscription out of range

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector, runtime-error

I'm new to C++ and have faced a problem dealing with vectors.

I need to access a vector declared in "GridClass" from another class, so I declared the vector as public and tried to populate it. Here's my code.

GridClass.h

```
#include <vector>

class GridClass : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(GridClass)

public:
    GridClass(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~GridClass();

protected:
    int nItem, nSubItem;

public:
    std::vector<CString> str; // <--The vector
```

In the GridClass.cpp;

```
str.reserve(20);//This value is dynamic
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    str[i] = GetItemText(hwnd1,i ,1);// <-- The error occurs here
}
```

I cannot use an array as the size is dynamic, I only used 20 for debugging. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you would be better off adding an accessor to your vector instead of exposing the member variable - always try to keep classes decoupled as much as possible, it makes your life easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) only increase the capacity of vector, it doesn't allocate elements, `str.size()` is still `0` which means vector is empty.,  you need [std::vector::resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) in this case:

```
str.resize(20);
```

Or just call `std::vector::push_back`

```
str.reserve(20);   // reserve some space which is good. It avoids reallocation when capacity exceeds
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    str.push_back(GetItemText(hwnd1,i ,1)); // push_back does work for you.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The vector is still empty after calling `reserve`; you still need to add strings with `insert` or `push_back`, or empty strings with `resize`.

To use your loop to populate it with ten strings, use `push_back`:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    str.push_back(GetItemText(hwnd1,i ,1));
}
```

or if you want 20 strings, assigning the first 10 and leaving the rest empty, then you could keep your loop, but use `resize` rather than `reserve`.